# Get picture to Android from .net WebService

Tags: android, .net, web-services

I have a WebService in VisualBasic .net that gives a picture with the following code:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function DevuleveImagen() As Byte()

    Dim imagen As Byte()
    Dim bm As New Bitmap("C:\Imagen.jpg")
    Dim ms As New IO.MemoryStream

    bm.Save(ms, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    imagen = ms.GetBuffer()
    ms.Close()
    ms = Nothing


    Return imagen

End Function
```

And I try to recive this picture from Android:

```
private void PonLogo(){

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME1);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    try {
          HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
          androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope);
          SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
          if(result != null)
          {
                Object o = result.getProperty(0);
                byte[] b = o.toString().getBytes();
                Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
                imgbannerjuego.setImageBitmap(bMap);
          }
          else
          {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Response",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
    } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And debuging everything seems to be ok, but when the app starts, the place where I should see the picture is white. I think that could be a conversion problem, but I do not know how can I solve it.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: i have the same issue , i appreciate if you can share the solution if you found it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Could you put some logcat log? I guess there is an exception because you handle network event in the UI thread. Try like this.

```
  private void PonLogo(){
    final SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME1);
    final SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                  HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                  androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope);
                  SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
                  if(result != null) {
                      Object o = result.getProperty(0);
                      byte[] b = o.toString().getBytes();
                      Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
                      yourActivity.runOnThreadUi(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          imgbannerjuego.setImageBitmap(bMap);
                      });
                  }
             } else {
                      yourActivity.runOnThreadUi(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Response",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      });
              }
        } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }).start();
    }
```